# I want to sum the looped textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, while-loop

Hi guys I am new to javascript and php and I have a problem
I'd like to sum the looped text box but I am lack at logics
here is the code

```
<form name="rec" action="this.php" method="post" > 
<?php 
$x = 0; 
while($x<=5){
$x++; 
echo "<input type='text' name='n". $x."' id='n". $x."'>< input type='text' name='y". $x."' id='y". $x."'>
<input type='text' name='res". $x."' id='res". $x."'>";
}
?>
<input type="button" value="Compute" onclicked="compute()">
</form>

< script > 
ctr = 0<
while(ctr<=5){
ctr++;
x = Number(document.getElementById("n"+ctr).value)
y = Number(document.getElementById("y"+ctr).value)
ans = x+y;
document.getElementById("res"+ctr).value = ans;

} 
< /script>
```

I would like to get the out put of like this

[image]

Thank you I am not really specific :D

Comment: sorry really I dunno how to use stackoverflow T_T
and in the script

< script >
function compute()
{ 
ctr = 0<
while(ctr<=5){
ctr++;
x = Number(document.getElementById("n"+ctr).value)
y = Number(document.getElementById("y"+ctr).value)
ans = x+y;
document.getElementById("res"+ctr).value = ans;

}
} 
< /script>

Comment: try my following code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<form name="rec" action="#" method="post">
<?php
$x = 0;
while($x<=5){
$x++;
echo "<input type='text' name='n". $x."' id='n". $x."'><input type='text' name='y". $x."' id='y". $x."'>
<input type='text' name='res". $x."' id='res". $x."'><br>";
}
?>
<input type="button" value="Compute" onclick="compute()">
</form>

<script>
    function compute()
    {

var ctr = 0;
while(ctr<=5){
ctr++;
var x = Number(document.getElementById("n"+ctr).value);
var y = Number(document.getElementById("y"+ctr).value);
var ans = x+y;
document.getElementById("res"+ctr).value = ans;

}
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `compute` function? You should enclose the contents of the `<script>` tag with `function compute()`.

Comment: inside the script <script>function compute(){ctr = 0<
while(ctr<=5){
ctr++;
x = Number(document.getElementById("n"+ctr).value)
y = Number(document.getElementById("y"+ctr).value)
ans = x+y;
document.getElementById("res"+ctr).value = ans;

} } </script>